# Entry linking 2.1 with dynamic categories

Tags: categories, entry, links, entrylinks

I am using Entry Linking 2.1 to display prev/next entries in the SAME cateogry as the current single entry page.

I cannot get the plugin to recognize the current category unless it is hardcoded.  I tried low segtocat and it will not work in the Entry Linking code.

```
{exp:entry_linking entry_id="{entry_id}" link="previous" channel="portfolio" orderby="entry_date" status="Open|Sold" sort="asc" mode="short" category="{segment_3_category_id}"  no_results="cycle"}
<a href="{path={segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/{link_url_title}}"><</a>
{/exp:entry_linking}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
category="{categories backspace="1"}{category_url_title}|{/categories}"
```